# How to use svg text tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I can use SVG Text tag in javascript. But its doesn't work. These is my code for Javascript.

```
O=evt.target;
Doc=O.ownerDocument;    
L = Doc.createElementNS(xmlns, "text");
L.setAttribute("x", 10);
L.setAttribute("y", 10);
L.node.textContent("abcdef");
L.setAttribute("fill", "red");
O.appendChild(L);
```

SVG Text Tag for Example:

```
<text x="10" y="10" fill="red">abcdef</text>
```

What type of error in my javascript code.
Regards, Viji

Comment: xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"      Its my xmlns.

Answer (score 2):

This perfectly works

```
​<svg>
    <text x="10" y="10" fill="red">abcdef</text>
</svg>
```

H​​​​​​​​​​​​​ere is a working javavascript [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wwRnc/1/). I don't have your complete code so it's hard to pinpoint your exact problem.

**Edit:**
I think I found it. `L.node.textContent("abcdef");` should be `L.textContent = "abcdef";`
[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwRnc/2/)

More examples [here](http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/text/js_dom/index.htm).

Comment: @Viji No problem! Would you mind marking it as answer? Thanx!